# Nodejs app not able to connect with angular app on 3000 port if angular app hosted on remote machine.

Tags: node.js, angular

Nodejs app not able to connect with angular app on 3000 port if angular app hosted on remote machine.

But able to connect if both app (nodejs and angular) are hosted on a single machine. What configuration am I missing? 
Sharing below nodejs server app code.

```
var OrderServer = /** @class */ (function () {
    function OrderServer() {
        this._orderService = new order_service_1.OrderService();
        this._pushNotificationSenderService = new push_notification_sender_service_1.PushNotificationSenderService();
        this.createApp();
        this.defineApiRoutes();
        this.config();
        this.createServer();
        this.sockets();
        this.listen();
    }
    OrderServer.prototype.getApp = function () {
        return this.app;
    };
    OrderServer.prototype.createApp = function () {
        this.app = express();
        this.app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            next();
        });
        this.app.use(express.json());
    };
    OrderServer.prototype.defineApiRoutes = function () {
        this.app.route('/api/notifications')
            .post(add_push_subscriber_1.addPushSubscriber);
    };
    OrderServer.prototype.config = function () {
        this.port = process.env.PORT || OrderServer.PORT;
    };
    OrderServer.prototype.createServer = function () {
        this.server = http_1.createServer(this.app);
    };
    OrderServer.prototype.sockets = function () {
        this.io = socketIo(this.server);
    };
    OrderServer.prototype.listen = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.server.listen(this.port, function () {
            console.log('Running server on port %s', _this.port);
        });
        this.io.on('connect', function (socket) {
            console.log('Connected client on port %s.', _this.port);
            setInterval(function () {
                _this._orderService.getNewNProcessingOrders(_this.io);
                //this._pushNotificationSenderService.sendNotification();
            }, 180000);
        });
    };
    OrderServer.PORT = 3000;
    return OrderServer;
}());
exports.OrderServer = OrderServer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `proxy.conf.json` file within the root folder of the angular project.

[AngularCLI Documentation about proxies.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

**Example content:**

```
{
  "proxy": {
    "target": "https://localhost:3000/",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^proxy": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Then in environment files for the angular app `angular/root/folder/environments/` create a url base for `development` (environment.ts) and `production` (environment.prod.ts) and use this prefix everywhere where you want to access the backend.

**Example environment configuration**:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  backendBaseKey: '/proxy/'
```

};

**Angular service example:**

```
// Depending on dev/prod the according env is imported
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";

[...]

fetch(){
  return this.http.get(environment.backendBaseKey+'/my-endpoint');
}
```

Then when running locally go via

`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`